# Swagger UI generation for generic REST calls

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

**What do I want:**

I want to be able to generate swagger documentation that passes a key/value into the URL. This so that I can use generic arguments controller to handle my requests like Dictionary.

If swagger can't generate it, is there a way to generate the documentation by using reflection on my objects? This so that I can still use generic methods

If not, what would be the best way to let everyone know what the correct approach would be.

**Why do I want it**

I'm developing a new API and I'm using swagger to create the documentation. In this API I want to work with some generic methods to prevent hardcoding things. For example on the `PATCH` method I use a `Dictionary<string, string>` to get the property/value combination and in the `GET` I use a custom object as the argument. In both cases, swagger can't generate the correct parameter fields, because it takes the argument as url key.

**Example action & form - incorrect**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Patch(int id, Dictionary<string, string> viewModel)
{
    return await ConnectionWrapper(() => connector.Patch(id, viewModel));
}
```

[image]

This uses the body, not the query

**Other examples - incorrect**

In the GET I have a model with a custom modelbinder to handle all the rest URL arguments. The problem is because the model is defined it sees the filter as a property.

[image]

Then it is in the URL, but it will look like http://example.com/controller/method/id?sort=prop_asc&filter=propTwo%3D=value, instead of http://example.com/controller/method/id?sort=prop_asc&propTwo=value

**Desired output**

[image]

I've modified the HTML to simulate what I would like in the picture above. The URL that would be called would be http://example.com/controller/method/id?propertyName=propertyValue.

I don't mind if there would be only one option to add a generic key/value pair because with it I can demonstrate what I want.

**Expected solution**

I think the solution lies in the `MapType` startup method of swagger or in an implementation of the `IOperationFilter`, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Looks like this is not supported yet: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/298

Comment: I know that it isn't supported straight out of the box, but since almost every best practice about rests emplies this usage of the url arguments like this I figured I wouldn't be the only one with this and someone maybe knows a workaround. Or at least how to use swagger in such a way that I can inform the users what the correct way should be.

Comment: Swagger 2.0 (which you are using) does not actually support dictionaries in the query string. It's supported in the latest spec, OpenAPI 3.0. You'll probably have to wait until both Swashbuckle and Swagger UI implement that feature. Or maybe implement it yourself and submit a PR.

Comment: Last version seem to support OpenAPI 3.0, you should retest and tell us if it works :)